# Updating pandas index and row in nested while loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, while-loop, generator

I am facing the challenge iteratively updating `row` and `index` in a for loop that makes use of the `pd.iterrows()` generator.  In the example below, my objective is to get the distance between each consecutive letter and the *first* letter (A) starting from index 0:

```
import pandas as pd
import string
 
data = {'letter':['A', 'C', 'D', 'X', 'X', 'Z', 'A', 'E', 'Z', 'Y', 'D', 'B', 'A']}
 
start_idx=df['letter'].iloc[0]

for index, row in df.iloc[1:].iterrows():
    
    dist= abs(string.ascii_uppercase.index(df['letter'].iloc[0]) - \
              string.ascii_uppercase.index(df['letter'].iloc[index]))
              
    print(dist)
2
3
23
23
25
0
4
25
24
3
1
0
```

That is easy enough. However, if the distance exceeds 5, then I would like to start comparing the following letters to the last "normal" letter whose distance from the previous was <= 5 using a while loop and append the indexes of letters that deviate.  For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import string
 
data = {'letter':['A', 'C', 'D', 'X', 'X', 'Z', 'A', 'E', 'Z', 'Y', 'D', 'B', 'A']}
bad_letters = [] 
    

start_idx=df['letter'].iloc[0]
compare_letter = string.ascii_uppercase.index(df['letter'].iloc[0])

for index, row in df.iloc[1:].iterrows():
                                              
    dist= abs(compare_letter-string.ascii_uppercase.index(row['letter']))  
    
    if dist > 5:
                                              
        compare_letter =  string.ascii_uppercase.index(df['letter'][index-1]) #reset compare letter
        abnormal=True

        while abnormal:
            
            bad_letters.append(index)
            dist=abs(compare_letter-string.ascii_uppercase.index(df['letter'][index]))
            index+=1 #increment index
            
            if dist <=5:
                abnormal=False
                compare_letter=string.ascii_uppercase.index(df['letter'][index])
                #?update iterrows index with this index#
                break
            
        else:
            continue
```

The output list `bad_letters` **should** be: [3,4,5,8,9] which correspond to:

-the index of letters **X,X,Z** which deviated more than 5 from D at index 2
-the index of letters **Z,Y** which deviated more than 5 from letter E at index 7.

The above attempt fails, and I am not sure how to structure this properly in a way that effectively uses `iterrows()` with a while loop.  How would one use a while loop inside of `iterrows()` or a different pandas dataframe generator to answer this basic question?  How can one iteratively "update" the **index and row** of the original for loop with the index that breaks the nested while loop? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage less than and cumsum here to flag consecutive values exceeding the threshold and the prior value that doesn't.  Based on that you only needs groups > 2, for which you can compare those groups values to the first value in the group, and output those which are still too far away.

```
import pandas as pd
 
data = pd.DataFrame({'letter':['A', 'C', 'D', 'X', 'X', 'Z', 'A', 'E', 'Z', 'Y', 'D', 'B', 'A']})

data['dist'] = data.letter.apply(ord)-ord('A')
data['group']  = data.dist.lt(5).cumsum()


data = data.groupby('group').filter(lambda x: len(x)>1)
data = data.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: (x['dist']-x['dist'].iloc[0])>5).reset_index()

data.loc[data['dist']==True]['level_1'].values
```

Output

```
array([3, 4, 5, 8, 9], dtype=int64)
```